# CXF Jax-RS server service returning only header but no response JSON

Tags: rest, cxf, jax-rs

I have a very basic Rest Server which returns JSON object. I tested it with Poster Firefox extension and I get both header and response.
But we have a test javascript client, which calls the service and when checked with Firebug, we see there is a header but no response.
To be sure, we tested the client with another JSON server and the client can read both the header and response.

As I mentioned, it is a very basic Apache CXF, Jax-RS service, so we are not sure what could be missing , that prevents from sending response or prevents client from reading response.

Will appreciate any help or input.

thank you
Walker

Comment: It wasn't the server it was the client which was not able to read the response properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't the server it was the client which was not able to read the response properly.